# проверка ввода данных

Tags: java, echo

Пытаюсь реализовать команду echo чтобы выводило текст сообщения. 
Как сделать проверку? Через  equals у меня не выходит так как переменная текста у меня не объявлена, а в проверку я ее не могу засунуть
Конструктор класса echo имеет такой вид

```
EchoText(String echo, String text)
{
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Как мне сделать проверку что я ввожу этот текст?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Enter  the command:");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        if (s.equals("help"))
        {
            Help h = new Help();
            h.execute();
        }
         if(s.equals("echo" + " " + //тут нужен текст что будет выводится))
        {
            EchoText f = new EchoText("echo" , //параметр конструктора для текста);
            f.execute();
        }
        else if (s.equals("date now") )
        {
            DateNow dn = new DateNow();
            dn.execute();
        }
        else if (s.equals("exit"))
        {
            Exit e = new Exit();
            e.execute();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте s.trim().indexOf("echo ") - если 0, то отлично строка начианается с этой последовательности. Далее - s.trim().substring(5) - то что идет после эхо, делаете с ней что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, решил эту задачу с помощью проверки, начинается ли эта строка с заданного префикса startsWith(String prefix), а потом да сабстрингом вынул то что мне нужно. Спасибо за внимание!